# Octopus requires explicit Channel ID when creating release via API despite default channel being set

Tags: .net, octopus-deploy

I'm using Octopus Server. At one point within my pipeline, I run a lambda function that pushes the build package to Octopus, and then attempts to create a Release within Octopus.

I'm using the .NET Octopus SDK.

Pushing the package to Octopus works smoothly.

Creating the release throws this error:

```
There was a problem with your request. - A channelId must be provided for a release when more than one exists for that project and no default channel has been specified.: OctopusValidationException
at Octopus.Client.OctopusClient.DispatchRequest[TResponseResource](OctopusRequest request, Boolean readResponse)
at Octopus.Client.OctopusClient.Create[TResource](String path, TResource resource, Object pathParameters)   at Octopus.Client.Repositories.ReleaseRepository.Create(ReleaseResource release, Boolean ignoreChannelRules)
at MyProject.Function.CreateRelease(ILambdaContext context, S3Entity s3Event, IOctopusSpaceRepository repositoryForSpace) in /home/runner/work/CICD/CICD/src/MyProject/Function.cs:line 113
at MyProject.Function.FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context) in /home/runner/work/CICD/CICD/src/MyProject/Function.cs:line 84
at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
```

... after running this:

```
var release = new ReleaseResource(version, "MyProjectId");
repositoryForSpace.Releases.Create(release);
```

The error message seems self-explanatory, and I can fix it quickly by explicitly referring to the Channel when creating the `ReleaseResource`, like this:

```
var release = new ReleaseResource(version, "MyProjectId", "MyChannelId");
```

But the error message seems to be a bug, because

1. I only have one channel, and
2. That one channel is marked as the `default`

So I would think that with even just ONE of those conditions `true`, I wouldn't receive this error. Yet, I receive it even with both conditions satisfied.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could be a bug. Can you email support@octopus.com with the error, your Octopus.Client version, and your Octopus Server version?